# Extremizing sum and difference of lengths using triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, triangles, coordinate-systems

We have three points $P=(2,3)$, $Q=(4,-2)$ and $R=(\alpha,0)$. We need to find the value of $\alpha$ such that:

[image: The Triangle[1]]

Part 1: $|PR+QR|$ is maximized.

Part 2: $|PR-QR|$ is minimized.

I have  the solution for both. I have understood the solution for case 1 but not for case 2.

Case 1's solution : https://i.stack.imgur.com/z18eZ.jpg

Case 2's Solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drhqU.jpg

I have understood case 1 completely but in case 2 why was there a need to take the image of point Q? I fail to understand this.

Comment: I dont understand why they took image of point Q (4,-2)  in case 2.

Comment: Part 1 asks for the minimum of $|PR+QR|$. The maximum doesn't exist
And the difference is maximized. Probably you have swapped the questions

Comment: @Raffaele. Yes the maximum would be at Infinity. The solution of minimum would be case 1's answer.

Comment: @Raffaele am i correct ?

Comment: @user33699: You posted the identical question 2 hours earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2458444/42969.

Comment: @MartinR because no one was answering them.

Comment: Have a look at [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) for possible options – reposting the identical question is not one of them. And it often takes longer than 2 hours (sometimes days) until one gets an answer.

Comment: @MartinR even just after an hour my posts get burried beneath all the new stuff.

Comment: @user33699: Related on Meta: [Is double posting allowed if a question is not answered after some time?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26282/42969) – [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/42969) – [Should I delete and repost my question to regenerate interest?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3795/42969)

Comment: Either you or the person providing the solutions mixed up which to maximise and which to minimise. The solutions are 1. for **minimising** $PR + QR$ (no absolute value needed, since the lengths are nonnegative), and 2. for **maximising** $\lvert PR - QR\rvert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer i was felt that too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum of $|PQ+QR|$ occurs when $R$ is collinear with $P$ and $Q$ because of the triangular inequality $|PQ+QR|\geq PQ$ then $|PQ+PR|$ is minimum when $PQ+PR|=PQ$.

To find the maximum of $|PQ-QR|$  call $Q'$ the symmetric of $Q$ wrt $x$-axis, then $QR=Q'R$ and remember that in a triangle a side is greater than the difference of the other two so $|PR-Q'R|\leq PQ'$ and the maximum for $|PR-Q'R|$ is when $R$ is collinear with $P$ and $Q'$, the intersection of the line $PQ'$ with $x$-axis.

Line $PQ'$ has equation $x+2y=8$ and substituting $y=0$ we get $x=8$ that is the solution $\alpha =8$

Hope it helps

PS

Try to use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), it's free  and is available for any kind of computer included tablets and smartphones. You can even use it online [here](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing)

Comment: Why do we need to use the symmetric of Q wrt x axis. Why cant we work with the point Q ?

Comment: @user33699 because we have to do the *difference* and $|PR-RQ|$ would be maximum  when R is collinear with $PQ$, that is  intersects $x$-axis which is false

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's correct.

Clearly $|PR-QR|$ is minimized when $PR=QR$. The locus of points for which this is true is the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$; since the midpoint is $(3,1/2)$ and $Q-P = (2,-5)$, the direction of the bisector is $(5,2)$ and the perpendicular bisector intersects the $x$-axis at $(3,1/2) + (-1/4)\cdot (5,2) = (7/4,0).$

Comment: Yes you are correct. We needed to take the absolute value.

Comment: The value of alpha comes to be 8 in case 2. So the point R would be (8,0) ao that |PR-QR| is minimum.

Comment: @user33699 I think the solution you linked is wrong. I do not agree that $8$ is the correct answer (I just proved the answer is actually $\alpha = 7/4.$ It's also clear if you look at the picture that $\alpha$ near $7/4$ makes $|PR-QR|=0$.)

Comment: Details added...

Comment: I dont understand why they had to take image of point Q (4,-2) in digram of case 2.

Comment: [Somebody mixed up which to maximise and which to minimise.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458444/extremizing-sum-difference-of-lengths-using-triangle-inequality/2458514#comment5080637_2458444)